# Part load definition with respect to hydraulics

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics

I have read that variable speed hydraulic drives have very low part-load efficiency - due to losses in the internal pumps and motors.

What is part-load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part-load is when the full power possible of the drive / motor is not used or needed. The efficiency is lower due to the losses becoming more significant compared to the lower power produced as some of the losses may be independent of power produced.